# How to calculate area of intersection between raster and polygon in a web map?

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service

I need to calculate the area of intersection between a vegetation raster and a polygon drawn by the user in an ArcGIS Server JavaScript API web-map, as in this mockup:

[image]

After the user has drawn the polygon, the web map should return the total area of vegetation within the polygon.

I'm in the early stages of investigating this problem so I don't yet know the final data formats, but assume that the raster contains `1` to show where vegetation exists and `NODATA` where it doesn't, and that is has been projected into square metres.

Presumably the raster will be served as a tiled layer, although I'm open to other suggestions (Image Server?).

I don't believe there is any functionality in the ArcGIS Server JS API to calculate the area of intersection between a raster and a vector. In that case, is the correct approach to write a geoprocessing function to handle this on the server?

Comment: Have you explored the Raster Analytics service REST API? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Raster_Analysis_service_tasks/02r3000002s1000000/

Comment: @Brad nope, I'd never even heard of that API. It looks promising - thanks for the tip